# How to choose a specific class to instantiate in running time in Java?

Tags: java, instantiation

I get about 20 classes with name A, B, C,...X, Y, Z.

And the user will send me some message, I will choose one of classes to instantiate depend on the content of message. The message is as same as the name of its corresponding class's name.

I can write a switch case statement to do this, like:

```
switch (msg):
  case "A" :
    class = new A();
    break;
  case "B" :
    class = new B();
    break;
  case "C" :
    class = new C();
    break;
...
```

Is there a more concise way to do that? I cannot image how boring the coding is if I get 1000 classes.

Comment: `Class.forName("Some.claz.Name")`

Comment: 1000 classes? Are you sure you designed properly the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Class.forName()` for this:

```
Class c = Class.forName("foo.bar.MyClass"); // requires full class name including package
Object object = c.newInstance();
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) of `Class.forName()` for more details. These features are called reflection. Oracle provides a nice [documentation section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) for these kind of features.

Comment: BUt I still get one question: If I want to cast the object to Class.forName("myclass01"), how to do this?

Comment: `Class` has a `cast` method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29

Answer (score 2):

The others have suggested using a factory and they are right.

I prefer to use an `enum` for my factory.

```
interface I {

}

class A implements I {

}
class B implements I {

}
class C implements I {

}
enum Factory{
  A {
    @Override
    A create() {
     return new A(); 
    } 
  },
  B {
    @Override
    B create() {
     return new B(); 
    } 
  },
  C {
    @Override
    C create() {
     return new C(); 
    } 
  };

  // Constructors.
  abstract I create();

  // Construct a named class.
  public I create(String type) {
    return Factory.valueOf(type).create();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29):-

```
Class myclass = Class.forName("Your.Class.MyClass");
Object o= myclass .newInstance();
```

**forName()**

> Returns the Class object associated with the class or interface with
>   the given string name.

Answer (score 0):

1. Obtain a `Class` instance from a `ClassLoader`, passing in the name you need.
2. Call `newInstance` on it.

Answer (score 0):

First off, this sort of problem is inherent with good design.  The kind of method you are talking about is a [Factroy Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

You can use case, but more typically one uses an if-else block.  So...

```
if(msg.equals(A)) {
  return new A();
} else if(msg.equals(B)) {
  return new B();
} ....
```

Here assuming A & B are Strings, I like to define them as constants (`public static final`).

While both are a bit messy, most of the time people use the if-else block it is more standard procedure.

Answer (score 0):

as i see everyone has own solution, so i show you mine

you need:

```
    interface MyInterface {
    }

    class A implements MyInterface {
    }

    class B implements MyInterface {
    }

    interface Factory {
    MyInterface createInstance();
}

    class FactoryA implements Factory {

    @Override
    public MyInterface createInstance() {
        return new A();
    }
}

class FactoryB implements Factory {

    @Override
    public MyInterface createInstance() {
        return new B();
    }
}

enum MyEnum {
    A(new FactoryA()), B(new FactoryB());
    Factory factory;

    MyEnum(Factory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    MyInterface getInstance() {

        return factory.createInstance();

    }

}
```

then all what you need to do is to create lookup table, and your switch statement will be replaced by `MyEnum.find(msg).getInstance()`

with this solution you dont need to worry about handling any exception